# How can I cut the last char from a string in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

suppose that i have

> var name = "kanishka";

How can I cut only the last char so that the output will be 'a' instead?

i read the question

> How can I cut the 1st char from a
>   string in jquery?

by jin Yong ,

> in this problem i know the length of
>   the string . can u tell me how i can
>   do this with out knowing the string
>   length .

couldn't get help from the answers , please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using plain javascript, you can do

```
name.charAt(name.length-1)
```

More information on charAt http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp

Comment: Finally someone using their brain and not substring (which is pointless and stupid for this case)! +1. of course, given that a string is an array, you can even do `name[name.length-1]`.

Comment: @OJ: Why do you think `substring()` is worse than `charAt()` here, apart from being a few characters longer? By the way, accesing characters in a string via numeric property names is non-standard prior to ECMAScript 5 and is not supported in IE 7 or earlier (not sure about IE 8).

Comment: @Tim: `[]` is supported in IE8. Not, as you said, in IE7 or earlier. @OJ: Strings are not arrays. `String` supports `[]` on modern browsers, but it's still not an array.

Answer (score 4):

```
Array.prototype.pop.apply(name);
```

^_^

or if you want to be boring:

```
name.substr(name.length-1);
```

or:

```
name.split('').reverse().shift()
```

or:

```
name.split(name.substr(0, name.length-1)).pop()
```

or:

```
name.constructor.prototype.charAt.call(name.split('').reverse(), 0)
```

or:

```
var chr; name.split('').forEach(function(c){ chr=c; });
```

or (okay, these are serious):

```
/.$/.exec(name)[0]
```

or

```
name[name.length-1];
```

Comment: They're all boring given that to pull out a single char you can index directly into the array and avoid all of the overhead that you've suggested.

Comment: @OJ - what, don't like my unnecessary overhead?!?  :(

Comment: @OJ: You can only use `[]` if you don't care about IE6 and IE7 support. (IE6 + IE7 make up 10-20% of the browser users out there, a figure that is -- **thankfully!** -- rapidly falling, but still significant).

Comment: @TJ Yes mate, you're right. Those browsers are a PITA. I personally refuse to support browsers that old (2 major version numbers behind is a joke, and IE10 isn't far off). Let's make it our duty to get people to update :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the "a" in "kanishka":

```
var name = "kanishka";
name = name.substring(name.length - 1);
```

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/aqeve5)

Comment: what's with all the `-2` in the answers?  That'll give you 'ka'

Comment: @cwolves: It was a typo, apparently you saw it before I fixed it. :-)

Comment: *clicks the button* aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: `name.slice(-1)` is a little neater.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = name.substr(name.length-1,name.length);
```

Comment: he wants the last char, not the string up to the last one

Comment: try again!  :)  What you want: `name.substr(name.length-1)`

Answer (score 1):

**A roundup of your options** as presented by the various answers here:

 *(note that this is a CW answer, as it represents community content)*

1. `substring`:

   ```
   var lastChar = name.substring(name.length - 1);
   ```

   - Verbose, but clear.
   - Broadly-supported.
2. `substr`:

   ```
   var lastChar = name.substr(name.length - 1);
   ```

   - Verbose *(thought a tiny bit less so)*, but clear.
   - Broadly-supported *(though not **strictly** standard, and there are edge cases with some browsers; see comments)*.
3. `slice`:

   ```
   var lastChar = name.slice(-1);
   ```

   - Concise, clear once you're used to the idiom, but unclear to non-l33t c0d3rz.
   - Broadly-supported.
   - Tends to be slower or slowest on most browsers *(but not all)*.
4. `charAt`:

   ```
   var lastChar = name.charAt(name.length - 1);
   ```

   - Verbose, but *very* clear.
   - Broadly-supported.
   - Fastest (or tied for fastest with `[]`) on most browsers (usually by a fair margin).
5. `[]`:

   ```
   var lastChar = name[name.length - 1];
   ```

   - Concise and clear.
   - **Not supported** by IE7 and earlier.
   - Fastest (or tied for fastest with `charAt`) on most browsers (usually by a fair margin).

(Due respect to cwolves' flights of outre approaches, I stuck to the mainstream like the boring plodder I am.)

[Gratuitous jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/get-last-char-of-string)

Which should you use? It's totally up to you. Note that all of the options above are plenty fast, the odds that the speed of this operation are actually important in 99.999% of real-world cases are very low indeed.

Comment: `substr()` isn't strictly standard, although as you say, it is broadly supported. Its implementation is slightly different in IE 7 (again, not sure about 8 or 9) from other browsers in that a negative character index is treated as 0 rather than being subtracted from the length.

Comment: @TIm: Hey, look at that. It's not in the main spec, but in an appendix on it (B.2.3, to be precise, in both 3rd and 5th editions). No wonder I never use `substr`. :-)

Comment: J.: `slice()` is where it's at for substrings in JS. It's standard, has negative offsets for teh l33t c0d3rz and is universally supported.

Answer (score 0):

A neat, short, cross-browser way is

```
name.slice(-1);
```

Comment: Nice. :-) Curiously, this tends to be a slow option on several browsers (not that it matters), and I can't think why. See the CW post rounding up the options.